# php data insert into mysql utf8 not working

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, insert

I have 3 php files and 1 sql file. When I insert data in MYSQL on my language it works but, when I go in ADMINPHP and check base it shows me similar ნიკა symbols. What can I do for this problem? [THIS IS MY FILE LINK](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxI5okXQ2XCyfmJVWEZXTWthQ3poUjlEalVkMUh4ckJEQ3AzbFRoVnNraEVic2UtdXg3azA&authuser=0)

Answer (score 1):

make sure all fields you entering the data into are set to utf-8, and run the following query after selecting the db

```
SET NAMES utf8
```

Comment: how can i set in php file ?

Comment: run this query after you selecting the db in your php code

Comment: you have this line in your code add the query after the line mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB"); 

add this query:
mysql_query('mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8'));

Comment: i make but nor fixed :(

Comment: when you create the table it takes the default charset I assume it is not utf so change your create table declaration to: CREATE TABLE `test_mysql` (
`id` int(4) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`saxeli` varchar(65) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`gvari` varchar(65) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`asaki` varchar(65) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`nomeri` varchar(65) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(65) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

Comment: Please provide `SELECT HEX(col), col FROM ... WHERE ...` for something that you suspect is stored incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Something is not set to UTF-8.

1. Check the database settings.  Make sure everything is UTF-8.  Run these commands in your database using the MySQL command line, MySQL Workbench, PHP MyAdmin, or any other database client:

   `-- Check the charset of the database
   SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';`

   `-- Check the collation of the database
   SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'coll%';`

   `-- Check the charset of the schema
   SELECT default_character_set_name FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA S
   WHERE schema_name = "schema_name";`

   `-- Check the charset of each table
   SELECT CCSA.character_set_name FROM information_schema.TABLES T,
      information_schema.COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY CCSA
   WHERE CCSA.collation_name = T.table_collation
     AND T.table_schema = "schema_name"
     AND T.table_name = "table_name";`

   `-- Check the charset of each column
   SELECT character_set_name FROM information_schema.COLUMNS C
   WHERE table_schema = "schema_name"
     AND table_name = "table_name"
     AND column_name = "column_name";`
2. Make sure the content type of your html document is UTF-8.  You can check this in the Firebug console.  You can also add code like the following to your webpage to set it:

`<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>`

3. Check the character set of the client you are using (MySql Workbench etc). If you are using PHPMyAdmin, make sure the following settings exist in **config.inc.php**:

   `$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en-utf-8';
    $cfg['DefaultCharset'] = 'utf_8';
    $cfg['DefaultConnectionCollation'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
    $cfg['Lang'] = 'en-utf-8';`

Comment: im database everything are in utf 8

Comment: I've added more checks for you.  Check your schema, tables, and columns using the code above.  Something is not UTF-8 in your system.  IMPORTANT NOTE: If you find something somewhere that is not UTF-8 and you then correct it so that it is UTF-8, it's not going to convert any existing data in your database.  To test it you will need to insert new data using your application.

Answer (score 0):

Modify table field using

```
ALTER TABLE <tab_name> MODIFY <field_name> DATA_TYPE NOT NULL  COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ;
```

When saving file using php, use this line of code before run query

```
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");
```